# GCP & Fluentd: Enhance container logs with env vars

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-kubernetes-engine

I've googled all day and it seems like I have no idea of what to google ;)

So what I want to do is to enhance the logging of my containers which run in the google cloud.
The logs are being gathered by fluentd.

My specific yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TEST
          value: "test123"
        name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.8 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

As you can see I have an environment variable called 'TEST' with the value 'test123'.

What I want to do now, is that fluentd appends this key/value pair to EACH log line... Is this so hard or am I not even able to do this?

Any help or links would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I don't think there's an easy way (or any way, really) to have FluentD add environment variables defined within a pod's containers to the log messages sent by those containers.

Your best bet would be to actually change the Syslog configuration of the containers of that pod in such a way that it'd add those environment variables to the log messages. You can then easily filter those messages via a new ConfigMap for the default FluentD DaemonSet running by default on Kubernetes clusters hosted on Google Cloud **IF** you want to do any kind of additional processing to them.

By filter, I mean actually filtering messages according to their content. The default FluentD deployment uses a container that doesn't include `fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter`, so you can't filter by pod name AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the sample fluentd from kubernetes which comes with fluentd kubernetes metadata, then instead of adding it to the env alone, add it as a label.  From there fluentd will by default add kube metadata on every log.